# Are "over-visible" and "over-visibility" correct/idiomatic words?

Tags: word-choice

I want to say that someone is too visible, as in the following sentence:

> Unlike philosophers who suffer from invisibility in the society,
>   sociologists enjoy **over-visibility**.

Is the use of "over-visibility" in the above sentence correct?

Comment: You just asked this question yesterday. "Over-visibility" was not idiomatic yesterday and it is still not idiomatic today. Voting to close as duplicate.